# download one file from VHD link

Tags: azure, vhd

I was using Azure VM and my subscription was disabled. there were some files that I was working on in the last few days without backup on my local device. now I got a link to the machine VHD but it's too big and my connection is very slow. Is there is any way to download only my files from that link without downloading the whole file?
my file is almost 1 MB and the image is 127 GB. I know that the best solution is to make another subscription but I only have a pre-paid card now any they don't accept that

Answer (score 1):

If you have VM's backup you can perform a [file level restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-restore-files-from-vm). If you have 'just a link' to VHD file unfortunately there is nothing you can do to download single file - sorry.